# Escaping filenames when passing as an argument

Tags: java, string, escaping

My Java program is launching another process and passing a file's absolute path as command line argument. The path may contain spaces. So I am quoting the path before adding it to the arguments. When a double quote appears in the path, I am escaping it with `\`.

Here is the code:

```
private String escapeQuotes(String original) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
        if (original.charAt(i) == '"') {
            builder.append('\\');
        }
        builder.append(original.charAt(i));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

I use it like,

```
String args = " \"" + escapeQuotes(filePath) + "\"";
```

This works well. But I am wondering is this approach fool proof? Or is there anything else that I should handle like the way I have escaped double quotes?

Any help would be great!

Comment: For which environment are you building this app? On Windows at least, file names can't contain double quotes, so escaping them is unnecessary.

Comment: I don't think it's fool proof. In cases, where they already are escaped, you double escape them. Maybe use a regex instead?

Comment: @jlordo I will not get escaped file paths here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to do this, eg

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"cmd", "/c", "dir", "d:/test ;test"})
```

works fine, note that "f:/test ;test" contains bot ' ' and ';'

Answer (score 1):

How are you launching the other process? If you are using the [version of Runtime.exec that takes an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) then there is no need to escape spaces in any of the arguments.

e.g.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "notepad.exe", 
    "c:\path with spaces\afile.txt" });
```

Comment: I am doing this in a subclass of `JavaLaunchDelegate` from the eclipse JDT.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment under the post: IMHO, the method is not *fool proof* because it would also escape quotes that are already escaped. I would use:

```
private String escapeQuotes(String original) {
    return original.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\"", "\\\\\"");
}
```

Then

```
System.out.println(escapeQuotes("Not escaped\", escaped\\\""));
```

prints

`Not escaped\", escaped\"`

in the console, whereas your version would print

`Not escaped\", escaped\\"`